# How to access a mobile inbuilt stereo camera using ros?

Tags: ros, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have LG optimus 3D p 920 android phone and would like to know how its stereo cameras can be accessed using ROS.I would like to publish left and right camera messages just like when we connect 2 cameras on usb for constructing stereo image.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237836/how-to-access-a-mobile-inbuilt-stereo-camera-using-ros?/) by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you need is to create a node that uses image transport and camera info manager. The image transport is the standard way to publish images in ROS and the second shares the calibrated camera information. I imagine that you will have to somehow broadcast the images from your phonte to the pc running ROS and then your node should receive and publish the video feed you receive.

Cheers...

---

Originally posted by [Nexus8](https://answers.ros.org/users/26736/nexus8/) with karma: 106 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0